Validation in multistep form with jquery steps not working while skipping steps
I have a form with 7 steps and there are validation in each step.
onStepChanging and onFinishing logics are as following:
` var form = $("div#wizard").show();
var formWizard = $("#form1");
form.steps({
headerTag: "h1",
bodyTag: "section",
transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
 onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
     //if ($stopChanging) {
     //    return true;
     //}
     //else {
     // Allways allow previous action even if the current form is not valid!

     if (currentIndex > newIndex) {
         return true;
     }

     // Needed in some cases if the user went back (clean up)
     if (currentIndex < newIndex) {

         if (currentIndex == 0) {
             ActiveState = 0
             DPForm.SaveDPFormStep1();
         } else if (currentIndex === 1) {
             ActiveState = 1
             DPForm.SaveDPFormStep2();
          
         } else if (currentIndex === 2) {
             ActiveState = 2
             DPForm.SaveDPFormStep3();
         } else if (currentIndex === 3) {
             ActiveState = 3
             DPForm.SaveDPFormStep4();
             
         } else if (currentIndex === 4) {
             ActiveState = 4
             DPForm.SaveDPFormStep5();
             
         } else if (currentIndex === 5) {
             ActiveState = 5
             DPForm.SaveDPFormStep6();
         }

        
     }
     //debugger;
     formWizard.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
     return formWizard.valid();
   },
 onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex) {

formWizard.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";

//console.log(formWizard.valid());
return formWizard.valid();

},
 }`

There are some conditionally hidden fields like if I tick a checkbox a hidden block becomes visible and validation should work on the hidden block other wise validation should be bypassed.
Now the problem is when I set formWizard.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
validation for hidden fields bypasses but in this case when I jump from step 6 to step 4 empty some required fields and jump to step 1 change a field which causes a block to be visible in step 5, without going to step 5 I directly jump from 1 to 6 and finish the form steps.This will cause the validation not to work in skipped steps 2,3,4,5 even though there are visible fields and they satisfy validation rules.
and when I set  formWizard.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
this will validate conditionally hidden fields also.
How can I tackle this problem? Any suggestion will be appreciable.
I'm expecting a solution in which my hidden fields should not be validated but skipped steps should be validated.
